# select only and only specific record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with truck and locations , each truck can have many records with each location:
ex:

```
truck | location
----------------
60111 | 1
60111 | 2
60111 | 3
60111 | 4
60222 | 1
60222 | 2
```

....etc

I want to select the trucks with ONLY locations in (1,2).
in my example the return must be 60222 ONLY

how to do this?
Note: I want a dynamic solution not hard coded.

Comment: How do you mean 'I want no hard-coded solution'?

Comment: I mean I dont want a solution like: select truck where location in (1,2) and not in (3,4) because these number change all the time.... I want 1,2 and exclude all the rest

Comment: You can achieve this using Ranking functions. Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can group by the truck, filter on the location and check the result is 2:

```
select truck
from   table
where  location in (1, 2)
group
by     truck
having count(distinct location) = 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `HAVING` condition be `= 2`?

Comment: it is working for you @hamzeh ?

Comment: You should use `having count(distinct location) = 2`. But the query will also return trucks with location 1,2,3

Comment: The `distinct` is necessary _if_ a truck has a location twice. I find that more explicit than `>= 2` without a distinct. But it would still return trucks that have more locations than just 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

A solution similar to the one of Patrick Hofman is to move the logic in the `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT truck
FROM   table
GROUP BY truck
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) = 2
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN location IN (1, 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

The first condition return the truck with only two distinct location, not checking their values, the second condition force those location to be 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

This will select trucks that have **exactly** locations 1 and 2:

```
select t1.truck
from truck_location t1
where t1.location in (1, 2)
group by truck
having count(distinct t1.location) = 2
   and count(distinct t1.location) = (select count(*) 
                                      from truck_location t2
                                      where t2.truck = t1.truck);
```

The `distinct` inside the `count()` is only necessary if a truck could be assigned to the same location twice. If the combination truck/location is guaranteed to be unique this is not necessary.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b865f/1

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct truck
from
my_table
where 
truck not in
(
  select distinct truck
  from   my_table
  where  location not in (1, 2)
)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Won't this query return also trucks that have only location 1 or only location 2?

Comment: @ypercube: yes, you are right.